# Update MySQL Table column with Google Sheets Table column

Tags: javascript, mysql, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a MySQL Table in my database, and in another hand a table in Google Sheets.

My Goal is to update **MySQL Table** column with **Google Sheets Table** column.

MySQL Table name is `Winners`

MySQL Table column name is `Winner`

Google Sheets Table Column Range is `LNW!P5:P35`

For this I created a function to get `JDBC` database connection in Apps Script.

and coded the below. But it didn't work.

**Because ALL ROWS VALUES of google sheets are going to ONE ROW to MySQL**

I think this can be possible by **Loop Function**. But I don't know JS very well.

So How to fix this by splitting Range Values and post to **MySQL in ROW BY ROW**  ..?

```
function UpdateDB(e) {

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName("LNW");
  winners = sheet.getRange("P5:P35").getValues() ;

  server = "give.herosite.pro";
  port = '3306';
  dbName =  "oncjsznl_wp921";
  username = "oncjsznl_wp921";
  password = "xxxxxxxx";
  url = "jdbc:mysql://" + server + ":" + port + "/" + dbName + "?characterEncoding=UTF-8";

  conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.execute("UPDATE `Winners` SET `Winner`='" + winners + "' ;");

  conn.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How to loop through rows

- `getValues()` returns you a 2D array containing rows and columns of your range
- Assuming that your function is working as intended, but you would like to use a loop to push data row by row - you can modify your code as following:

```js
function UpdateDB(e) {

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName("LNW");
  winners = sheet.getRange("P5:P35").getDisplayValues() ;
  
  server = "give.herosite.pro";
  port = '3306';
  dbName =  "oncjsznl_wp921";
  username = "oncjsznl_wp921";
  password = "xxxxxxxxx";
  url = "jdbc:mysql://" + server + ":" + port + "/" + dbName + "?characterEncoding=UTF-8";

  conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
  stmt = conn.createStatement();

  for (i=0 ; i<31 ; i++ ) {  
    stmt.execute("UPDATE Winners SET Winner ='" + winners[i] + "' WHERE Id = " + (i+1) + " ;");
  }

  conn.close();
}
```

See [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp).

Comment: I tried this inside function. 
  ```for (let i = 1 ; i-1 < winners.length,;  i++ ) {
  text +=  "UPDATE Winners SET Winner ='" + winner + "' WHERE Id= " + i + " ; " ;
```  But didn't work. getting syntax error.

Comment: Hi @PrabhuPaul! The sample I provided was about how to use a for loop, as for the exact format of your database and the query you would like to use to put the data in  - this is something I cannot help you with.

Comment: As for using a `for` instead of `forEach` loop - this is also possible (but has exactly the same result like `forEach`), however you need to declare `winner` within the loop (otherwise it throws an error). A correct usage of the `for` loop would be `for (let i = 0 ; i < winners.length;  i++ ) { let winner = winners[i]; ...}`.

Comment: Hi @ziganotschka I used ```for``` loop like this. ```for (i=0, r=1; i<31, r<32; i++, r++) {       stmt.execute("UPDATE Wtest SET Winner ='" + winners[i] + "' WHERE Id = " + r + " ;");   }``` It's worked very well.

Comment: I believe you can simplify your request as `for (i=0; i<31; i++) {       stmt.execute("UPDATE Wtest SET Winner ='" + winners[i] + "' WHERE Id = " + (i+1) + " ;");   }` - would that not work for you?

Comment: Yes it had worked by ```removing 2nd variable``` of for loop. I have edited your answer according to this, pls approve it to mark it as ```ANSWER``` Thank You